# Changing the language in English/Persian in android programming

Tags: android, custom-keyboard

I've got a question for you.

I made a keyboard by using [this link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615) then, I wanna assign a button for changing the language in English/Persian , but I can't assign this button to do so, I mean I don't have a clue how to do it.

Help me please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this solution.
Generally our keyboard there're two mode: English mode & Persian mode, we switch one to other if click on the button you mentioned. As I understand, when change language mode, we have 2 things to do:
1. Change the language on each key button
2. Change the language display on TextView.

With the first one, you just need to prepare 2 image resource due key buttons. Each time switch language mode, reset drawable for each button.
About the second, every key will contain a list of character which will be displayed on TextView when you press. So you could initialize two list character for each key, one in E and other in Persian. Due to the mode & key was press, you get the appropriate character and append to TextView.
Hope this usefull.